# Can I upload a video to YouTube from my own site

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Is there a YouTube API that will allow me to upload a video to my YouTube account from my own website and return the embed code which I can store in my website database.

I want to add a name, description, custom URL and embed link all which goes to my online database. The embed should be returned from YouTube so I can then store it online and it can be read.

Comment: I'd start here https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started

Answer (score 9):

You can make use of the insert API of YouTube developers.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

To upload you can use this authorization: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload

If successful, this method returns a video resource in the response body. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource

This might be helpful for your need.